# Using GAE/UserService to login to XMPP

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-talk

I am working on a problem solving game which will be hosted on GAE. I use the UserService API to validate the user before letting them play the game. During the game, I would like to update the users gtalk status to something like "User X is on step y of the game". Is this possible?
I toyed around with smack library and I could do it, provider I knew the password. However, in my GAE scenario I rely on the UserService. How can I login to XMPP using GAE UserService?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't have access to change the status message of the user

Comment: maybe they use a google api that allows that ... but if you found a service that allows that with a big "source code" link on the bottom, why don't you look how they do it ?

Comment: Doh! I feel like a dork. I read everything but the bottom links.

Comment: Ok. They ask for the answer later on.
I will take it that it is not possible possible and look for other alternatives. Thanks Bastian.

Answer (score 0):

The XMPP service provides 'bot accounts' on a dedicated domain, which you can use to send and receive XMPP messages on any connected network. It doesn't give you access to a user's gtalk account, or let you authenticate as arbitrary XMPP accounts.